# How can I run a background program in docker container

Tags: docker

I want to run a container, but it is a background program (for example: tinyproxy, I make the image tinyproxy_local)

---

```
docker run -d tinyproxy_local tinyproxy
```

this will exit because tinyproxy is a background program.

---

I can do it like this:

```
docker run -it tinyproxy_local bash
/#: tinyproxy
/#: ctrl+p ctrl+q
```

this can be running, but I want the tinyproxy can be auto started when I restart the container. I tested it:

```
docker run -d tinyproxy_local tinyproxy && sleep 99999999999
```

I think the container can keep running when sleeping, but it don't work.

---

How can I run a background program in docker container, and It can be auto started when I restart the container?

---

**Or is there any small forground program, that can keep container running**?
(I have tried `sleep 99999999`, but it didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run your docker processes in the foreground.

With tinyproxy I believe it is the `-d` flag (source: https://www.mankier.com/8/tinyproxy).

**Edit based on comments:**

If your entrypoint runs two processes - one your app, and another the tinyproxy - you should separate them to two containers, and run tinyproxy in the foreground with the -d flag. Another source of information can be this [tinyproxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/travix/tinyproxy/dockerfile) docker.

Sticking to one process per container will save you headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use nohup

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup sh -c programname &
```

Comment: This will background the nohup process. This is no better the the tinyproxy backgrounding itself.

Comment: Is there any small foreground program, to ensure that the container doesn't exit? The best is that it is a system program, and I don't need to install it